# Printing Barcode Label not working

Tags: vb.net

I am using Sato CX400 Barcode Printer to print Barcode From vb.Net application
Label size on which barcode is printing is 28 x 21 mm and 3 label per row (3ups) 
i am making crystal report and adjust printing area as per label size and gap.
now when Call for print Label of any one product ( i.e. if i given 3 ) then crystal report
display Preiview of 3 label per row. Now when call for print from preview , then barcode printer print one row with 3 label and it is ok.
but when i call for more than 3 label printing then crystal report display perfect report what evre no of label u want to print, but when printing from this preiview barcode printer print only one row (3 label per row) and then stop printing.

i am talking about this to barcode printer supplyer they run other barcode printing software and printing barcode label as per given number by us (ie 1,2,3,4......)
 and its working fine.

now i want to know what is problem in my software , why it is printing onle one row 
is there any setting for printing barcode?

plz help me to comeout from this problem.

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

**Mailing Label Type**
You can define your own label type by selecting User-Defined Label from this list. However, to make your work easier, the program comes with preset templates for many other label types. Those labels are listed in the Mailing Label Type list.

When you choose a preset label template, the program automatically sets up the specifications for that label.

---

**Label Size**
These edit boxes enable you to specify the dimensions (height and width) of one label. This information can usually be found on the box or folder the labels come in. Simply enter the height and width values in the respective edit boxes.

Note:    The unit of measurement used in the dialog box (inches or centimeters) is based on settings in the Regional Options of the Windows Control Panel.

***Gap Between Labels***
These edit boxes enable you to specify the empty area (gap, gutter, and so on) between labels. Simply measure the gaps and then enter the horizontal and vertical values in the respective edit boxes.

**Horizontal** 
The gaps between labels going across the page. One-up (one across) labels don't have any horizontal gaps.

**Vertical** 
The gaps between labels going down the page.

Note:    The unit of measurement used in the dialog box (inches or centimeters) is based on settings in the Regional Options of the Windows Control Panel.

---

**Printing Direction**
The Printing Direction section enables you to specify the path that the program follows when printing the data on your labels.

Across then Down 
Prints data left to right across the first row of labels, then across the second row, and so on.

**Down then Across** 
Prints data down the first column of labels, then down the second column, and so on.

**Number of Labels**
This information box displays the maximum number of labels that can print across the page and the maximum number that can print down the page based on your settings in the Page Margins, Mailing Label Size, and Gap Between Labels edit boxes and paper size (which is set up in Windows Control Panel).